# Java EE 7 First Cup Tutorial errors in Maven: Could not find artifact org.glassfish.javaeetutorial.firstcup:firstcup:pom:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, netbeans-7, java-ee-7

I'm following along with the Java EE 7 updated version of FirstCup. I have glassfish 4 installed and am using NetBeans 7.3. I'm working on the very first example and I'm getting maven issues.

I generated the archetypes and am able to create the dukes-age project. However it has non-resolvable maven issues:

Could not find artifact org.glassfish.javaeetutorial.firstcup:firstcup:pom:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Here is the full error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.mycompany:dukes-age:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/koblentz/NetBeansProjects/dukes-age/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact    org.glassfish.javaeetutorial.firstcup:firstcup:pom:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
```

I'm not really sure what to do/how to fix this. I deleted my local cache in the .m2 repo and tried building from the commandline instead of using NB to run the maven commands.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it. The pom generated by the archetype is looking for 7.0.1-SNAPSHOT and the actual version in m2 repo is 7.0.1 without the SNAPSHOT on the end.

Comment: Thanks for stating the problem, but what actions did you take to fix it? I'm having this same problem.

Comment: @Nocturno in the pom.xml in `<parent></parent>` I had to change `<version>8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` to `<version>8.0</version>`.

Answer (score 7):

Filed this issue as:
https://java.net/jira/browse/FIRSTCUP-14

The workaround is to replace the parent definition:

```
<parent>
<artifactId>firstcup</artifactId>
<groupId>org.glassfish.javaeetutorial.firstcup</groupId>
<version>7.0.1</version>
```

I'm working on getting an updated package in the Update Center.

Comment: Version 7.0.1-6 is now in the Update Center with this fix.

Answer (score 2):

To get it to resolve the parent pom, you also need to install the examples application tutorial at NetBeans/glassfish-4.0/docs/firstcup/example/pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, in my case it was because I copied the glassfish folder with the example in to the **C:\programs** folder and Netbeans, **after i copied it in Documents all works fine**.