# load hello_stateless_ejb project from pom

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, pom.xml

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453163/262852), while I was [looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111335/where-is-dukes-age-in-maven-archetype-per-first-cup-of-jee7/25132779#25132779) `tut-install`, I poked around in glassfish and found:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll glassfish4/samples/ejb/hello-stateless-ejb/hello-stateless-ejb-bean/src/main/java/enterprise/hello_stateless_ejb/StatelessSession.java
```

In and of itself, the code is minimal:

```
package enterprise.hello_stateless_ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface StatelessSession {

    public String hello();

}
```

I would like to run this sample, there's a pom file.  How can I load this project into glassfish?  I was trying to load `tut-install`, which would also be useful.  However, this example looks like, perhaps, a simpler version.

A stateless "hello world" sample is where I would like to start, preferably just by loading the pom.  I've glanced through some older EJB books, but they're woefully out of date; working code would be preferable.

the pom is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
                <groupId>org.glassfish-samples</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-samples</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>hello-stateless-ejb</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>hello-stateless-ejb</name>
    <modules>
        <module>hello-stateless-ejb-bean</module>
        <module>hello-stateless-ejb-client</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to package and deploy the project to run it on GlassFish (or any other application server). I would recommend to use NetBeans because it has a good GlassFish integration and also comes with a lot of working Java EE examples.

1. If you don't already have, download and install the NetBeans Java EE version from https://netbeans.org/downloads/. If you already have a running GlassFish server you can deselect the included GlassFish in the installation wizard.
2. If GlassFish is already running, shut it down.
3. In NetBeans, go to the `Services` tab, click on `Servers` and add your GlassFish instance.
4. Click on File -> Open Project and load the `pom.xml`. This should open 3 projects.
5. You probably want to deploy the `hello-stateless-ejb-bean`, right-click on the project and click `Run`, if it asks for a server select your GlassFish instance.
6. This should start GlassFish and deploy the project, you can see GlassFish logging in the output window of NetBeans.